# Java-Tile Map Image Flickering-What can i do to stop this?

Tags: java, arrays, 2d-games, pacman

I am making a pacman game and i have a MAP in an array, i assign the different values in the map to draw different images, in order to create a pacman map... but It keeps flickering all over the place

Any help with identifying the problem would be wonderful

I realize that this is a lot of reading, but i have looked at it for hours and not figured it out.... I am new to programming so I think that more experienced eyes could really benefit me

### Draw Map

```
public void drawMap() {
    BufferStrategy bs = this.getBufferStrategy();
    do {
        do {
            Graphics g = null;
            g = getGraphics();
            try {
                for (int x = 0; x < graphics.map.width; x++) {
                    for (int y = 0; y < graphics.map.height; y++) {
                        tile = graphics.map.level1[y][x];
                        //System.out.println(y + ", " + x);
                        int tileX = x * 21; //(int) (x * 21.42857142857143);
                        int tileY = y * 26; //(int) (y * 25.80645161290323);
                        if (tile == 0) {
                            g.drawImage(wall, tileX, tileY, 21, 26, null);
                            //System.out.println(x + ", " + y);
                        }
                        if (tile == 1) {
                            //g.drawImage(space,tileX, tileY, (int)21.42857142857143, (int) 25.80645161290323,null);
                        }

                    }
                }
            } finally {
                g.dispose();
            }
        } while (bs.contentsRestored());
        bs.show();
    } while (bs.contentsLost());

}
```

### Render

```
public void render() {
    BufferStrategy bs = this.getBufferStrategy();
    do {
        do {
            drawn = false;

            Graphics g = null;


            try {
                g = bs.getDrawGraphics();

                if (MAIN_MENU == false && GAME == true) {
                    if (level1test) {
                        if (!drawn) {
                            drawMap();
                            drawn = true;
                        }

                        //g.drawImage(level1,0,0,getWidth(),getHeight(),null);
                    }

                    if (level2test == true) {
                        g.drawImage(level2, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), null);
                    }

                    g.drawImage(point, playerX, playerY, playerHeight, playerWidth, null);
                } else if (MAIN_MENU == false && GAME == false) {
                    g.drawImage(settingsBackground, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), null);
                } else {
                    g.drawImage(background, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), null);
                }
            } finally {
                g.dispose();
            }
        } while (bs.contentsRestored());
        bs.show();
    } while (bs.contentsLost());
}
```

### Run and Timer

```
public void run() 
{
    long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
    double nsPerTick = 1000000000 / 60D;
    long lastTimer = System.currentTimeMillis();
    double delta = 0;
    
    int frames = 0;
    int ticks = 0;
    
    while (running == true) {
        long now = System.nanoTime();
        delta += (now - lastTime) / nsPerTick;
        lastTime = now;
        boolean render = false;
        
        while (delta >= 1) {
            ticks++;
            tick();
            delta -= 1;
            render = true;
            
        }
        
            try {
                Thread.sleep(3);        //keep the Frames from going to high
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            
        if(render == true){
        frames++;
        render();
        }
        
        if (System.currentTimeMillis() - lastTimer >= 1000) {
            lastTimer +=1000;
            //System.out.println("Frames: " + frames + "   Ticks: " + ticks); 
            
            frames = 0;
            ticks = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

### Map Array

```
public static int width = 28;
public static int height = 31;

public static int[][] level1 = {
    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,},
    {0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,},
    {0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,},
    {0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,},
    {0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,},
    {0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,},
    {0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,},
    {0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,},
    {0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,},
    {0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,},
    {1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,},
    {1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,},
    {1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,},
    {1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,},
    {1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,},
    {1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,},
    {1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,},
    {1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,},
    {1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,},
    {0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,},
    {0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,},
    {0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,},
    {0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,},
    {0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,},
    {0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,},
    {0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,},
    {0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,},
    {0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,},
    {0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,},
    {0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,},
    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,}
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need double buffer, the problem is that java paints the canvas with the background color and then put the grahpics instructions, so, if you need to change the image you can do it in a "hidden image" and when it's ready print it in the canvas area replacing the image with the new rendered image.
More info here [Double Buffer in java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/fullscreen/doublebuf.html).
EDIT:
Almost forgot, is really easy to do it, here is an example [double buffer example](http://www.realapplets.com/tutorial/doublebuffering.html)

Comment: I tried doing this, it didn't work :(  ill update the question with my new code

Comment: ok, remember to check the example link, the idea is draw everything in the offset image and then paint it in the canvas, if you already have it in that way then i can review the parts and search is something is missing

Comment: And other thing, if you use threads and swing it's not recommendable to create the threads yourself (IDK if you're doing, because there are only fragments, but to keep in mind), but use SwingWorkers because some concurrency issues can arise, again, more info here http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=153